# Node.js easyimage callback not fired

Tags: javascript, node.js

The easy-image module on npm(https://github.com/hacksparrow/node-easyimage). I want to resize image to smaller, after successful resizing I want to execute specific function but it doesn't fire.

```
var easyimg = require('easyimage');
function resizeImg(callback) {
    easyimg.resize(
        {
            src: 'modules/public/uploads/original.png',
            dst: 'modules/public/uploads/thumbnails/original-resized.png',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        }, function(err, image){
            console.log('Success');
            callback();
        })
}

function someCallback(){
    console.log('I want to go to outside');
}

// run
resizeImg(someCallback);
```

It doesn't display any message including error message. No error message, and No success message. Do I have missed anything? 
Even if I use `.then` for promise it doesn't show any messages.

```
var easyimg = require('easyimage');

function resizeImg(callback) {
    easyimg.resize(
        {
            src: 'modules/public/uploads/2016040120234230.png',
            dst: 'modules/public/uploads/thumbnails/newname.png',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
        }).then(function(file){
        console.log('success');
    });
}
```

Comment: `easyimg.resize` function accepts only one argument so there's no way it could work the way you written it in the first piece of code.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner But it won't display `console.log` too.

Comment: Try to provide two functions in `then` as it is done in the README.md examples on repo website. You're missing `function(err){/*...*/}` as second argument.